# cluster data using gower metric and clusplot

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to cluster my data, 24 attributes (20 are categorical attributes and 4 are numeric). I used `cluster` package and Gower metric:

```
tabel <- read.table("file.csv", sep=",")
daisy.mat <- as.matrix(daisy(tabel,metric="gower"))
my.cluster <- pam(daisy.mat, k=5, diss = T)
clusplot(daisy.mat, diss = T, my.cluster$clustering, color = T)
```

but `clusplot` need too much time in my opinion (I have never used it before now and I don't know if it is normal)... I've been waiting for over two hour.

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How many rows are there in table?

Comment: 10929, thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think that you just have the arguments to clusplot wrong.  Try `clusplot(my.cluster, dist=daisy.mat, color=T)`

Comment: One hour ago I tried with your suggestion but until now nothing happens.. is it normal? Is it too much big the matrix?

Comment: It may be your matrix size. with 10929 rows your distance matrix has 119M entries.

Comment: thank you for your help! after 5 hours I have got the plot :) is it possible to know each cluster which examples contain?
thank you in advance!

Comment: I think that what you are asking for is in the variable `my.cluster$clustering`. It tells you which cluster each instance is in. If you want to know which points are in cluster 2, you can just use `which(my.cluster$clustering == 2))`

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to follow your suggestion but I didn't understand the output. (Sorry but I have been using R for a short time). If I use: output  <- which(my.cluster$clustering==2), and I try to do: output[20] it gives as output two values that are the same (in this case 40 40). why? Is 40 the index in the matrix of the example that belongs to the secons cluster? Thank you!

Comment: Yes,  that means that point number 40 is in cluster 2.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But why output [20] reported twice the same value?  How can I selected once of them? The type of data is not an array... sorry for my stupid questions!

Comment: Without actually having your data it is hard to know for sure, but what I think you are seeing is that the value is 40, but also the row name is 40.    Try something like `x=output[20]`.  I think  you will see that x is 40 but the other 40 will not be there.